# Converting dates to Mo/Yr text so I can group by Mo/Yr

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Heads up - I am a self-taught Newbie!  I am working in Sequel Server 2008r2.  I have a huge file of detail sales transactions.  I want to create a summary by salesperson by Mo/Yr that I can then import into SSRS and create a chart.  I would like my output to look like this:

```
Salesperson1   Jul 2012   5000.00
Salesperson1   Aug 2012   6000.00
Salesperson1   Sep 2012   7000.00
Salesperson2   Jul 2012   1000.00
Salesperson2   Aug 2012   2000.00
Salesperson2   Sep 2012   3000.00
Salesperson3   Jul 2012   4000.00
Salesperson3   Aug 2012   5000.00
Salesperson3   Sep 2012   8000.00
```

I have no trouble pulling the data and outputting the date as Jul 2012, for example.  The problem is it is not grouping correctly because it's breaking on each ACTUAL transaction date instead of grouping on just the Mo/Yr that I want.  Also, I'm currently outputting text, so it is listing the dates in alphabetical order instead of calendar order.  I am on a fiscal year, so I need July 12, Aug 12, . . . Apr 13, May 13, Jun 13.  I know it's doing it that way because of how I'm converting the date, but I don't know any other way to get the date out in the format I want.

```
CONVERT(CHAR(4),TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts,100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts,120) as [Mo/Yr]
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!   PS - when I look at the draft of my message, it's running the sample output together, but each salesperson/month should be on a separate row in the output table.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't convert dates to strings for this. Use the built in date manipulation functions such as `MONTH(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)` and `YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)`

So you might have a query elements like:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts) as [Year],
   MONTH(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts) as [Month],
   SUM(dbo.TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_tot_at) as [Charges],
   (RTRIM(P.lst_nm)) + ', ' + (RTRIM(P.fst_nm)) AS [Provider]
FROM
   [...]
GROUP BY
   YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
   MONTH(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
   (RTRIM(P.lst_nm)) + ', ' + (RTRIM(P.fst_nm))
ORDER BY
   YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
   MONTH(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)
```

This will be much faster, accurate and more efficient than changing the dates to Strings.

Another way to do the same action and keep a single field for the date is group by the first of the month. Then format that into a string as needed for a label.

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts), 0),
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(3) , DATENAME(month, TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)) + ' ' +
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(4) , YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)) AS MonthLabel,
   SUM(dbo.TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_tot_at) as [Charges],
   (RTRIM(P.lst_nm)) + ', ' + (RTRIM(P.fst_nm)) AS [Provider]
FROM
   [...]
GROUP BY
   DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts), 0),
   DATENAME(month, TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
    YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
   (RTRIM(P.lst_nm)) + ', ' + (RTRIM(P.fst_nm))
ORDER BY
   DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts), 0)
```

(But if you can format later in the process and not in SQL, it is best to do so. Handle dates as dates whenever possible, only convert to strings when you really need to. An example of why: if your presentation layer is capable of exporting to Excel, then a formatted date value will let the user do their own analysis in Excel, but if you are exporting pre-formatted strings, the user will need to do extra work to recover the date information. Also, sorting datenames alphabetically is usually not what the user wants.)

Comment: Thank you.  But it's not working yet.  Here is my whole SQL:  SELECT TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts as [Mo/Yr]
  ,sum(dbo.TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_tot_at) as [Charges]
  ,(rtrim(P.lst_nm)) + ', ' + (rtrim(P.fst_nm)) AS [Provider]
GROUP BY
   YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
   MONTH(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)
ORDER BY
   YEAR(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts),
   MONTH(TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts)

Comment: Here's the error message I get:  Column 'dbo.TPB105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Well, obviously not the WHOLE SQL - I eliminated the From and Where clauses because it was too long!

Comment: SQL server needs to be told how to calculate any columns that aren't in the group by. If the field is always the same within the existing group, then just add it to the group by conditions.

Comment: Tried that - got this message:  The multi-part identifier "TBP105_CHARGE_DETAIL.chg_srv_ts" could not be bound.

Comment: I copied and pasted the file/field name from my first select field to the second one and now that error is gone.  however, my output looks like this:                                                 Year Month Charges Provider
2012 6 -524.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2012 9 -60.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2012 11 -194.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2013 2 -759.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2013 3 60.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2013 4 11412.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2013 5 45601.00 JOHNSON, DANA
2013 6 52849.00 JOHNSON, DANA             and I really want the dates to look like:  Jun 2013, Jul 2013, etc can I take this output & convert to text string for the date?

Comment: With SQL, usually formatting is handled at another layer: where ever your output is headed. If the end result is an Excel Spreadsheet, then add a column with a formula to handle the formatting. but I'll update my answer with additional options.

Comment: Thank you.  My next step is to import the SQL into SSRS and create a chart.  Can anything be done there to convert the numeric dates or to format them as mm/yyyy?

Comment: Certainly, yes. That's exactly why you should keep them as dates in the query. The chart can be sorted by date, and so that a year from now, changing from "Jul 2013" to "July 2013" is just a format change in the report, not a change to the query. If you need to know how to do this, you should ask another question.